# PostgreSQL Auto Partitioning, StatementInvalid: PG::NullValueNotAllowed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm trying to import a huge address database from a set of CSV files. I following a [tutorial](https://medium.com/@StreamBright/creating-partitions-automatically-in-postgresql-7006d68c0fbb) to create postgres partitions automatically.

I create my database with eighteen fields. Every field is a varchar.
The field I want to use for partitioning is "comune".

Following the guide I create this function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_partition_and_insert() RETURNS trigger AS
  $BODY$
    DECLARE
      partition_comune TEXT;
      partition TEXT;
    BEGIN
      partition := TG_RELNAME || '_' || partition_comune;
      IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT relname FROM pg_class WHERE relname=partition) THEN
        RAISE NOTICE 'A partition has been created %',partition;
        EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE ' || partition || ' (check (comune = ''' || NEW.comune || ''')) INHERITS (' || TG_RELNAME || ');';
      END IF;
      EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || partition || ' SELECT(' || TG_RELNAME || ' ' || quote_literal(NEW) || ').* RETURNING patent_id;';
      RETURN NULL;
    END;
  $BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

And then

```
CREATE TRIGGER address_list_insert_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON address_list
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE create_partition_and_insert();
```

Now I'm trying to populate my database with Activerecord.

```
a = AddressList.new hash
=> #<AddressList id_egon: "380100018695509", regione: "VALLE D'AOSTA", provincia: "AOSTA", comune: "AOSTA", frazione: "", procom_2016: "007003", ist_sez: "0000179", ist_pro: "007", ist_com: "003", dug: "REGIONE", via: "SARAILLON", presso: "", colore: "", num_civ: "34", esponente: "", civ_extraurb: "", liv_serv100_30: " 30", linea_lunga: "s">
irb(main):040:0> a.save
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (7.0ms)  INSERT INTO "address_list" ("id_egon", "regione", "provincia", "comune", "frazione", "procom_2016", "ist_sez", "ist_pro", "ist_com", "dug", "via", "presso", "colore", "num_civ", "esponente", "civ_extraurb", "liv_serv100_30", "linea_lunga") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18)  [["id_egon", "380100018695509"], ["regione", "VALLE D'AOSTA"], ["provincia", "AOSTA"], ["comune", "AOSTA"], ["frazione", ""], ["procom_2016", "007003"], ["ist_sez", "0000179"], ["ist_pro", "007"], ["ist_com", "003"], ["dug", "REGIONE"], ["via", "SARAILLON"], ["presso", ""], ["colore", ""], ["num_civ", "34"], ["esponente", ""], ["civ_extraurb", ""], ["liv_serv100_30", " 30"], ["linea_lunga", "s"]]
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::NullValueNotAllowed: ERROR:  query string argument of EXECUTE is null
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function create_partition_and_insert() line 9 at EXECUTE
: INSERT INTO "address_list" ("id_egon", "regione", "provincia", "comune", "frazione", "procom_2016", "ist_sez", "ist_pro", "ist_com", "dug", "via", "presso", "colore", "num_civ", "esponente", "civ_extraurb", "liv_serv100_30", "linea_lunga") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18)
    from (irb):40
```

I cannot understand where is my error. Some values are of course empty

Answer (score 0):

You have a null in one of the variables used to build the EXECUTE in your function.

If any of `partition`, `NEW.comune`, `TG_RELNAME` are null then concatenating them to your string will give null. That is exactly what the error message says.

You don't seem to set `partition_comune` which is used in `partition` so that could well be the source of your null.

Remember NULL means "unknown" and anything + unknown is obviously unknown. Likewise x < unknown = unknown and unknown = unknown is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

Going to assume you need partitioning, since the data/index doesn't fit in memory.

What's the structure of the table
\d address_list?

There is either a column defined as not null

OR

Ensure that there is an escape clause for "VALLE D'AOSTA"

" is used in postgres for (specifying case sensitive) column names,

' is for enclosing strings.